# how to load config in spring-webflux without spring-boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, kotlin

I just take some experiments with spring webflux 5.0.0 and Kotlin, and I have problem with loading configuration from application.yml

For base project I start with this example [spring-kotlin-functional](https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-kotlin-functional) 
 
But there are only manual loading beans and routing without any loading from configuration files or example how to implement analog of @ConfigurationProperties class in such way.

I have try to take environment in beans section:

```
data class DbConfig(
    var url: String = "",
    var user: String = "",
    var password: String = ""
)

fun beans(): BeanDefinitionDsl = beans {
    bean {
        //try to load config from path=db to data class DbConfig
        env.getProperty("db", DbConfig::class.java)
    }

    bean<DBConfiguration>()

    //controllers
    bean { StatsController(ref()) }
    bean { UserController(ref()) }

    //repository
    bean { UserRepository(ref()) }

    //services
    bean { StatsService(ref()) }

    //routes
    bean { Routes(ref(), ref()) }
    bean("webHandler") {
        RouterFunctions.toWebHandler(ref<Routes>().router(), HandlerStrategies.builder().viewResolver(ref()).build())
    }

    //view resolver
    bean {
        val prefix = "classpath:/templates/"
        val suffix = ".mustache"
        val loader = MustacheResourceTemplateLoader(prefix, suffix)
        MustacheViewResolver(Mustache.compiler().withLoader(loader)).apply {
            setPrefix(prefix)
            setSuffix(suffix)
        }
    }
}
```

but there are only system properties in Environment

So the question is how to load configuration from application.yml and how to implement analog of @ConfigurationProperties in such functional style?

And do I understand correctly that without spring-boot all annotations (like @Bean, @Repository, @Transactional and other) will not work for Beans?

My sources: [github](https://github.com/evgzakharov/big_migration/tree/0.0.1/step4_migration_to_webflux)

**Update 2017-10-21**

Find a solution. The problem was related to the fact that there there were no any BeanPostProcessor. And after I include this two processors:

```
bean<CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor>()
bean<ConfigurationClassPostProcessor>()
```

annotations `@Configuration`,`@Bean` and `@PostConstruct` start to work. But annotation `@ConfigurationProperties` exists only in `spring-boot` dependency, and yml parsing classes I find only in `spring-boot-starter`..

After including dependency `spring-boot-starter` and adding `bean<ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor>()` to beans section, annotation `@ConfigurationProperties` start to work, but config from application.yml was also not included. So I add this section:

```
val resource = ClassPathResource("/application.yml")
val sourceLoader = YamlPropertySourceLoader()
val properties = sourceLoader.load("main config", resource, null)
environment.propertySources.addFirst(properties)
```

to `GenericApplicationContext` configuration. And now all work as I expect, but with including a dependency `spring-boot-starter`.

Full code sample: [version with fixes](https://github.com/evgzakharov/big_migration/tree/1.0.0/step4_migration_to_webflux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring boot is just a dependency management that build auto-configuration that you can override. 
All the feature are inherited from Spring framework and modules. So basically you could do the same with or without boot.

I'm not on webflux yet. But as you reference your other beans, you mat need to declare a configuration bean elsewhere.

I'm sure I'll help you with that...

Comment: Thanks for answer! But as I see, this annotations does'n work, or I do something wrong..

Comment: Oh, what was it ? You should post it to help others

Comment: Update post, and describe a solution.